# RSpec create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm using `factory_bot` to create objects for organisation, but here organisations are created before create call, and because of validation create request is not processed.

```
it 'should increase organisation count by 1' do
  expect do
    post :create, params: { organisation: attributes_for(:organisation)}, xhr: true
  end.to change(Organisation, :count).by(1)
end
```

What did I do wrong in this?

```
(0.6ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
(0.2ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  Organisation Exists (0.7ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "organisations" WHERE "organisations"."name" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["name", "Organisation 2"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Organisation Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "organisations" WHERE "organisations"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["email", "organisation@domain.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "organisations" ("name", "created_at", "updated_at", "email", "phone_number", "location") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "Organisation 2"], ["created_at", "2018-01-27 05:36:13.649627"], ["updated_at", "2018-01-27 05:36:13.649627"], ["email", "organisation@domain.com"], ["phone_number", "+918292929292"], ["location", "Karur"]]
Processing by Admins::OrganisationsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"organisation"=>{"email"=>"organisation@domain.com", "location"=>"Karur", "name"=>"Organisation 2", "phone_number"=>"+918292929292"}}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 127], ["LIMIT", 1]]
(0.1ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  Organisation Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "organisations" WHERE "organisations"."name" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["name", "Organisation 2"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Organisation Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "organisations" WHERE "organisations"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["email", "organisation@domain.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

When I try to print the count,

```
it 'should increase organisation count by 1' do
  p Organisation.count
  login_admin
  p Organisation.count

  expect do
    post :create, params: {organisation: attributes_for(:organisation)}, xhr: true
    end.to change(Organisation, :count).by(1)
  end
end
```

the log,

```
Run options: include {:full_description=>/Admins::OrganisationsController\ POST\ \#\ create\ with\ valid\ params\ should\ increase\ organisation\ count\ by\ 1/}
0
1

expected #count to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0
./spec/controllers/admins/organisations_controller_spec.rb:71:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
-e:1:in `load'
-e:1:in `<main>'
```

Comment: how is your `organisation` model look like? Also, `but here organisations are created before create call` this can't happen.

Comment: There are attribute validations in the model, I have edited my question with the count printed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Organisation` is created when `admin` object is created. There will an association between `admin` and `organisation`.
Show your `login_admin` method and factories of `admin` and `organisation` if further help needed.